# Problem with weasyprint, when running pyhton file

Tags: python, weasyprint

Hi I am trying to convert html document to pdf using weasyprint, but when ever I run the script an error appears
weasyprint is already installed.

Following is the script

```
from weasyprint import HTML, CSS

css = CSS(string='''
    @page {size: A4; margin: 1cm;} 
    th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
    ''')
HTML('html_report_jinja.html').write_pdf('weasyprint_pdf_report.pdf', stylesheets=[css])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\HP Zbook\F\Projects\Desktop App\Printing Test\export_to_htm_template to pdf.py", line 1, in <module>
    from weasyprint import HTML, CSS
  File "D:\HP Zbook\F\Projects\Desktop App\Printing Test\venv\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\__init__.py", line 325, in <module>
    from .css import preprocess_stylesheet  # noqa isort:skip
  File "D:\HP Zbook\F\Projects\Desktop App\Printing Test\venv\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\css\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import computed_values, counters, media_queries
  File "D:\HP Zbook\F\Projects\Desktop App\Printing Test\venv\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\css\computed_values.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ..text.ffi import ffi, pango, units_to_double
  File "D:\HP Zbook\F\Projects\Desktop App\Printing Test\venv\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\text\ffi.py", line 404, in <module>
    gobject = _dlopen(
  File "D:\HP Zbook\F\Projects\Desktop App\Printing Test\venv\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\text\ffi.py", line 391, in _dlopen
    return ffi.dlopen(names[0])  # pragma: no cover
  File "D:\HP Zbook\F\Projects\Desktop App\Printing Test\venv\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 150, in dlopen
    lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)
  File "D:\HP Zbook\F\Projects\Desktop App\Printing Test\venv\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 832, in _make_ffi_library
    backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)
  File "D:\HP Zbook\F\Projects\Desktop App\Printing Test\venv\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 827, in _load_backend_lib
    raise OSError(msg)
OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0-0': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'gobject-2.0-0'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/first_steps.html#windows

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a GTK issue. You can refer to [this](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/971) Issue thread for some possible solutions. Make sure that you have GTK3 cleanly installed.